# Rename [warzone2100] → [warzone-2100]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The game *[Warzone 2100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warzone_2100)* currently has the tag [warzone2100](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warzone2100). The convention on this site is to use hyphens wherever there is a space, so it should be migrated to [warzone-2100](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warzone-2100).

Since these two tags are so similar and the site prevents end users from migrating them, can a mod please migrate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems sensible. Tag renamed:

- [warzone2100](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warzone2100) → [warzone-2100](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warzone-2100).